# How to do this in HTML / XSLT?

Tags: xslt

We're working on moving some reports from SSRS to XSLT / HTML, but I'm stuck on how to properly do the below. Basically, there are a lot of `<itemid>`'s and `<location>`'s, but I'm not sure how to loop through? My XML result looks similar to below:

```
<CombinedResults>
    <Results>
        <Result>
            <itemid> GAC Test 2</itemid>
            <displayname> GAC Test 2</displayname>
            <salesdescription/>
            <inventorylocation>4</inventorylocation>
            <locationquantityavailable>10</locationquantityavailable>
            <locationquantitybackordered/>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <itemid> GAC Test 2</itemid>
            <displayname> GAC Test 2</displayname>
            <salesdescription/>
            <inventorylocation>2</inventorylocation>
            <locationquantityavailable>180</locationquantityavailable>
            <locationquantitybackordered/>
        </Result>
    </Results>
</CombinedResults>
```

My XSLT Looks like below, but only shows 1 item and 1 location, rather than showing the item for all locations:

```
  <xsl:template match="/CombinedResults">
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SOMESTYLESHEET"/>
      </head>
      <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Item ID</th>
        <th>Location Available</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Results/Result/itemid"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Results/Result/inventorylocation"/></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

I've also tried the below, which I think is close, but doesn't work:

```
  <xsl:template match="/CombinedResults">
    <html>
      <head>
        <!-- URL must have ampersands replaced with &amp; -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SOMECSS"/>
      </head>
      <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Item ID</th>
        <th>Location Available</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <!--
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Results/Result/itemid"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Results/Result/inventorylocation"/></td>
        -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Results/Result/">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="itemid"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
     </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no `<CombinedResults>` tag in your XML... please ensure the XML and XSLT actually match

Comment: Also, please show the _desired_ output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exact requirements are a little vague, but here's my guess as to what you need.

Assuming this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CombinedResults>
    <Results>
        <Result>
            <itemid> GAC Test 2</itemid>
            <displayname> GAC Test 2</displayname>
            <salesdescription/>
            <inventorylocation>4</inventorylocation>
            <locationquantityavailable>10</locationquantityavailable>
            <locationquantitybackordered/>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <itemid> GAC Test 2</itemid>
            <displayname> GAC Test 2</displayname>
            <salesdescription/>
            <inventorylocation>2</inventorylocation>
            <locationquantityavailable>180</locationquantityavailable>
            <locationquantitybackordered/>
        </Result>
    </Results>
</CombinedResults>
```

And this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/CombinedResults">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SOMESTYLESHEET"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item ID</th>
                        <th>Location Available</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Result"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Result">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="itemid"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="inventorylocation"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SOMESTYLESHEET">
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Item ID</th>
            <th>Location Available</th>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <tr>
         <td> GAC Test 2</td>
         <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> GAC Test 2</td>
         <td>2</td>
      </tr>
   </body>
</html>
```